# C++: Lorentz Factor Equation

Tags: c++, physics

I am entirely new to C++. I took a class in Python, but would rather continue learning in a language that is more useful. But I am redoing several of my assignments from that class in C++ just to help me get going.

This particular problem is to write code that would solve for the Lorentz Factor with the input of a fraction of the speed of light (velocity/c) which should be between 0 and 1. I am sure there is a very simple thing that I am doing wrong; something I may not be familiar with coming from Python. But help would be appreciated. I keep getting the answer "nan". Does it have something to do with my type declarations? From my understanding, since I'm working with decimals, I should use float right?

Here's the Lorentz equation (but keep in mind, my code is accepting v/c as one number):

[image: http://spiff.rit.edu/classes/phys200/lectures/ke_rel/eqn_gamma.gif]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>


using namespace std;

float lorentz_factor (float v) {
    float answer = 1 / sqrt(1 - exp(v));
    return answer;
}

int main() {

    float v;

    cout<<"Please enter a number between 0 and 1";
    cin>> v;
    while (!((v < 1) && (v > 0))) { // "v" should be entered as a fraction of     the speed of light.
        cout<<"Try again: ";
        cin>>v;                     // and only accepted if it is between 0 and 1
}
    float factor = v;
    cin.ignore();
    cout<<"The lorentz_factor is: "<< lorentz_factor (factor) << "\n";
    cin.get();
}
```

Help me on this.

Comment: Python and C++ both have their uses.

Comment: One thing to watch out for is that `1/2` yields `0.5` in Python but `0` in C++, due to integer division. That said, reduce your example by all the input operations and hard-code a single value, which should bring you closer to the minimal example. Also check the posting guidelines again for an explanation why a minimal example is required.

Comment: Normally, you use `double` for floating-point values.  `float` tends only to be used where storage space is the overriding concern (or where there's a need to be bug-compatible with a low-precision system).

Answer (score 7):

You have:

```
1 / sqrt(1 - exp(v))
```

But the Lorentz factor is:

```
1 / sqrt(1 - v*v)
```

Comment: So `exp(v)` is always > 1, leading to square root of a negative number. Hence the NaN